# Test suite reliability

Tags: python-3.x, automated-tests

I have a few test scripts in a test suite that tests web applications and some of the tests fail and some will not, How can I estimate the reliability of individual test suites programmatically using python. Is there a measure or equation to test the reliability of a test suite. What are the metrics I should take into consideration while calculating reliability. My output contains whether the tests in a test suite passed or failed, how much time it took, how many test cases are there in total, how many failed and each test is identified by an identifier.

Comment: Chances are the tests failing is not the fault of the suite. If you want to be absolutely sure, test with two different frameworks (e.g. `unittest` and py.test).

Comment: @timgeb Understood, but is there any metric to test the reliability based on failures of tests in a particular test suite?